# camel how to process json with streaming mode?

Tags: apache-camel

In order to read json and unmarshal in streaming mode what options are available in Camel OOB ? If not out of box how can this be implemented ?

I found camel-xstream which might help. Is streaming mode a default of this or do we need to do something else to make it read in streaming mode ?

There is also jackson streaming api. Is that accessible with camel ?

Some examples would help. 
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [JSON data](http://camel.apache.org/json.html) format, to to marshal and unmarshal Java objects to and from JSON.

Some thing like `.marshal().json(JsonLibrary.Jackson)` which uses Jackson Library, You can use others as well.

Following is a sample configuration to stream csv file content and convert to JSON and then call publish method of MyBean class.

```
  CsvDataFormat csv = new CsvDataFormat();
  csv.setDelimiter(","); 
  csv.setQuoteDisabled(true);
  csv.setUseMaps(true);
  csv.setLazyLoad(true);
  csv.setHeader(Arrays.asList("head1","head2","head3","message"));

from("file:///test/?fileName=test.csv&noop=true").split(body().tokenize("\n")).streaming().unmarshal(csv).marshal().json(JsonLibrary.Jackson).bean(MyBean.class,"publish").log("done.").end();
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the unmarshal with json format. like this:

```
.unmarshal().json(JsonLibrary.Jackson, YourClass.class)
```

or

```
.unmarshal().json(JsonLibrary.Jackson)
```

In the first example you can take it in your Pojo, for manipulate the datas in a process like this:

```
.process(new Processor() {
                        @Override
                        public void process(Exchange exchange) throws Exception {
                           YourClass yourClass = exchange.getIn().getBody(YourClass.class);
})
```