# How to process big JSON array with Apache Camel

Tags: java, json, jackson, apache-camel

I want to achieve something similar to CSV streaming processing:

```
//read input file
.split(body().tokenize("\n", 100, false)).streaming()
            .unmarshal(new BindyCsvDataFormat( ...
```

I can control the content of input file, for example, I can have each JSON object on new line without JSON start array and comma after each object:

```
{"id": "foo1"}
{"id": "foo2"}
...
```

And then follow the same flow as in CSV (split and stream), but I can't unmarshal using `ListJacksonDataFormat` or `.json(JsonLibrary.Jackson)`

How to do this? 
Or is there another way of reading big JSON array?

**Note:**
This processing has to be fast, so I can't afford unmarshal to csv then marshal JSON as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44618227/camel-how-to-process-json-with-streaming-mode) (which seems a gross workaround).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [camel how to process json with streaming mode?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44618227/camel-how-to-process-json-with-streaming-mode)

Answer (score 0):

You can use jsonpath to split JSon messages (and enable streaming for bigger messages in the Splitter EIP)

https://github.com/apache/camel/blob/master/components/camel-jsonpath/src/main/docs/jsonpath-language.adoc

Comment: while working with CSV I found out that processing in batches e.g. 100 objects at time is faster than processing one by one, but I don't see how I can do that with json path. I have just one big array with up to 10k small objects.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up with the following solution:

```
.split(body().tokenize("\n", 1_000, false))
.streaming()
.process(exchange -> {
    String[] body = exchange.getIn().getBody(String.class).split("\n");
    var records = new ArrayList<FooBar>(body.length);
    for(String line: body) {
         records.add(objectMapper.readValue(line, FooBar.class));
    }
    exchange.getIn().setBody(records);
})
```

`objectMapper` is `com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper`

For example, a 3.5 GB file was processed in ~1.2 min.